# How can I output the appendix in a separate pdf

Tags: hyperref, appendices, appendix

For conferences (such as ICML) you sometimes have to submit the appendix as a separate pdf.

In the Appendix I want to use packages such as `hypperref`/`cleveref` to reference to equations and theorems from the main paper and I want all counters continue counting from where I stopped in the main part: If there is already an equation (1) in the main part, there shouldn't be any equation (1) in the appendix (otherwise referencing to eq.~(1) can lead to misunderstandings).

I also want the solution to be compatible with bibtex. What is the best way to get this result?
I would imagine somewthing like setting a variable at the beginning of the document if eighter only the main paper, or only the appendix or both are put into the resutling pdf.

Is there a standard solution for this?

Comment: If you have the full PDF as your master document (say, 100 pages), then in a separate .tex file use `pdfpages` package to include pages 1-95, and a second .tex file to include pages 96-100 of the main document, would that be an option?

Comment: This should work in many cases, but I would like to have the References (biblography) in the appendix as well, this makes it more challenging.

Comment: Do you mean printing the References twice or once?